# Easy way to compare bitcoin node block to total block, check sync status

Tags: bitcoin-cli

I am familiar with bitcoin-cli getblockcount, but is there an easy way to compare this to the total block count to check my sync status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already on the command line, try:

```
wget -q -O- https://blockexplorer.com/q/getblockcount; echo
```

Comment: That's not even a URL, and hasn't been for years.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, it works for me. Did you try it?